# connecting a relationship between siblings in Php / Laravel / msql

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder, laravel-collection

I am currently connecting a relationship between siblings.

**Issue:** If Im on the main person with list of siblings and have record to database, but whenever I go to the one of the sibling, I can only view the main person, but not the other siblings.

**letters represents siblings**
*first scenario - (a : b,c,d,e,f)
second scenario - ( b : a )*

**expected output:** Whenever I go to the second sibling, in this case "b", Ideally it will show other siblings on the list.

**letters represents siblings**
*first scenario - (a : b,c,d,e,f)
second scenario - ( b : a,c,d,e,f )*

here is my code

This is to get the list of siblings under the main person and pass it into an array

```
$sibling_list = [$tree['id']];
    
    $sibling_list_items = YommFtRelationship::whereIn('type_id', $sibling_ids)
    ->where(function ($query) use ($sibling_list) {
        $query->whereIn('member_1_id', $sibling_list)
            ->orWhereIn('member_2_id', $sibling_list);
    })
    ->distinct()
    ->get(['member_1_id', 'member_2_id']);

    foreach ($sibling_list_items as $sibling) {
        $sibling_list[$sibling->member_1_id] = $sibling->member_1_id;
        $sibling_list[$sibling->member_2_id] = $sibling->member_2_id;
    }
```

This code is to make sure that the the `$sibling_list` is equal to the member on the other table

```
         $mergeSibling = DB::table('yomm_ft_relationships AS r')
     ->join('yomm_ft_members AS m', 'm.id', '=', 'r.member_1_id')
     ->whereIn('m.id', $sibling_list)
     ->get();
```

Im trying to call a function to create the relationship between siblings from $sibling_list which is an array from the result of the foreach.

```
         $mergeSibling->each (function (YommFtRelationship $relationship) use ($sibling_list, $is_biological, $sibling_ids){
         $this-> createRelationshipBetween(
            $sibling_list->getKey(),
            $sibling_list->getKey(),
            $sibling_ids,
            $gender,
            $is_biological);         
        });
```

Is my process correct. Cheers lad

As requested these are my tables

```
Relationship table
id
type_id
member_1_id
member_2_id
biological
marital_status
status
created_at
updated_at

Relationship types table
id
type
name
created_at
updated_at

ID  type       Name
1   mother     Mother
2   father     Father
5   sister     Sister
6   brother    Brother
7   daughter   Daughter
8   son        Son
9   peer       Peer
10  partner    Partner
11  caregiver  Caregiver
12  whangai    Whangai

Rembers table
id
region_id
visitor_id
last_name
first_name
middle_name
preferred_name
NHI
dob
deceased_at
sex_id
gender_id
sexuality_id
created_at
updated_at
```

Comment: can you add your database structure and what is your definition of siblings applied to your DB structure.

Comment: Provide `YommFtRelationship` and `yomm_ft_members ` table structure with example value , and provide your required o/p like values